# If each function is deprecated, how to recover the beauty that this function provides?

Tags: php

The typical algorithm of search until found, in PHP and for some arrays where we can't use the language array search functions (I think), could be implemented in this way:

```
    $found = false;

    while (list($key, $alreadyRP) = each($this->relatedProducts) && !$found) {
        if ($alreadyRP->getProduct()->getId() === $rp->getProduct()->getId()) {
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        // Do something here
    }
```

Please, take it as pseudocode, I didn't executed it. What I like about it, is that it gracefully stops if it is found what we are looking for.

Now, due to the "each" function is deprecated, I have to code something like this:

```
    $found = false;
    foreach ($this->relatedProducts as $alreadyRP) {
        if ($alreadyRP->getProduct()->getId() === $rp->getProduct()->getId()) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        // Do something here
    }
```

To put a "break" statement inside a "for" loop is ugly in structured programming. Yes, it is optional, but if we avoid it, the "foreach" will go through all the array, which is not the most efficient way.

Any idea to recover the efficiency and structure that "each" gives in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't find the `break` in the loop ugly; in fact, I find the `while list each` to be uglier.

Comment: Nothing ugly whatsoever about break - you can't complain about the performance of letting a loop run until the end when it is not necessary, and at the same time exclude the construct that exists exactly for that purpose as "ugly", that makes little sense.

Comment: If it's inside a function why not just `return` at that point instead of setting a `$found` variable or using `break` ?

Comment: I think repeated function calls like `$rp->getProduct()->getId()` when nothing has changed is more a problem.

Comment: But if you want to keep the while loop to avoid break at all cost, then use `next` instead of each.

Comment: The entire question is opinion asking for more opinions, so it's OT anyway.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, it is better to assign $rp->getProduct()->getId() to a variable, of course, but that's not what I am asking.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes, the question is oriented towards opinions, but, sorry for ask, what do the initials OT mean?

Comment: OT = Off Topic.

Comment: @JonStirling Then, if it is not a question suited to SO, in your opinion, where it must be asked?

Comment: @Víctor Somewhere where it's not off topic. That's for you to find I'm afraid.

Comment: @misorude In structured programming, it's better to limit the use of "break" to the "switch" structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a rewrite that doesn't involve extra variables, you can replace the [`each`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) call with calls to [`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) and [`next`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php):

```
do {
  $found = (current($this->relatedProducts)->getProduct()->getId() === $rp->getProduct()->getId());
} while (empty($found) && false !== next($array));
```

This is a mechanical translation, and it relies merely on the definition of `each` (emphasis mine):

> Return the **current** key and value pair from an array and **advance** the array cursor

It also suffers the same deficiency of the original `each` version: it doesn't handle empty arrays.

That said, please don't use `each`, or any of its siblings, for new code. *This from a guy who voted "No" on the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_7_2#each)!* Why? Because the performance sucks:

```
1017$ cat trial.php
<?php
$array = range(0, 999);                                                       

$begin = -microtime(true);                                                    
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {                                              
    reset($array);                                                            
    $target = rand(333, 666);                                                 
    do {                                                                      
        $found = (current($array) === $target);                               
    } while (empty($found) && false !== next($array));                        
}                                                                             
printf("%.5f\n", $begin + microtime(true));                                   

$begin = -microtime(true);                                                    
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {                                              
    $target = rand(333, 666);                                                 
    foreach ($array as $current) {                                            
        if ($current === $target) break;                                      
    }                                                                         
}                                                                             
printf("%.5f\n", $begin + microtime(true));                                   

1018$ php -d error_reporting=-1 trial.php
8.87178
0.33585
```

That's *nearly nine seconds* for the next/current version while not even *half a second* for the foreach version. Just don't.

Answer (score 3):

The beauty of the `each()` method is in the eye of the beholder, but there are other reasons to prefer foreach, including this interesting bit of information from [the RFC that led to the deprecation of `each()`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_7_2#each)

> The each() function is inferior to foreach in pretty much every imaginable way, including being more than 10 times slower.

If the purpose of the method is to  `// Do something here` if the `$rp` is not found in `$this->relatedProducts`, I think a more "beautiful" way to handle it would be to extract the search through related products into a separate method.

```
protected function inRelatedProducts($id) {
    foreach ($this->relatedProducts as $alreadyRP) {
        if ($alreadyRP->getProduct()->getId() === $id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Moving the related products search into a separate method is advantageous because

- It separates that functionality from the original method so that it becomes reusable instead of being tied to whatever `// Do something here` does.
- It simplifies the original method so it can focus on its main task

  ```
  $id = $rp->getProduct()->getId();
  if (!$this->inRelatedProducts($id)) {        
      // Do something here
  }
  ```
- It simplifies the search code because if it's contained in its own method, you can just `return true;` as soon as you find a match, so you won't need to break, or to keep track of a `$found` variable at all.

---

On the other hand, if this was my project I would be looking for a way to remove the need for this method by populating `$this->relatedProducts` so that it's indexed by ID (assuming ID is unique there) so the determination could be reduced to

```
$id = $rp->getProduct()->getId();
if (isset($this->relatedProducts[$id])) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each is basically a version of `current()` and `next()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php

`each()` gives the current array item, and moves to the next index.

`current()` gives the current array item, but doen't increment the index.

So, you can replace `each()` with `current()`, and inside your foreach use `next()` to shift the index up

`next()` gives the next item, and increments the index.

```
while (list($key, $alreadyRP) = current($this->relatedProducts) && !$found) {
    if ($alreadyRP->getProduct()->getId() === $rp->getProduct()->getId()) {
        $found = true;
    }
    next($this->relatedProducts);
}
```